# Downloading from website using the correct URL in Colab

Tags: python, download, google-colaboratory, urllib

I am going to download a `rar` file using colab from a [URL link](https://141.ir/storage/otffiles/00_04_11_%D8%A7%D8%B3%D8%AA%D8%A7%D9%86_%D8%AA%D9%87%D8%B1%D8%A7%D9%86_.rar). To do so, I am using the cell below:

```py
import urllib.request
import urllib.parse
url = "https://141.ir/storage/otffiles/" + urllib.parse.quote('00_04_11_استان_تهران_.rar')
### url would be eqaul to https://141.ir/storage/otffiles/00_04_11_%D8%A7%D8%B3%D8%AA%D8%A7%D9%86_%D8%AA%D9%87%D8%B1%D8%A7%D9%86_.rar
urllib.request.urlretrieve(url, "my_file.rar")
```

It works fine on my localhost machine. However, it doesn't work in Colab, and it sticks at the level of `create_connectivity()`.

My guess is that the problem is with the domain of the link, which is a number, and Colab interprets it as an IP address. But I am not sure since it works fine when I run in the localhost. Or maybe the host (141.ir) has blocked IP addresses from outside Iran. What can be done to allow me to download the document from this link using Colab?

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Why not `requests` or `httpx`?

Comment: @WaketZheng I tried requests, wget (through commands) and a few other things (like switching to R environment). None of them worked. About `httpx`, I am not sure. I did not try that. Can you be more clear about using this method?

Comment: May be the problem is that `Colab` do not allow to access outside internet by HTTP...

Comment: @WaketZheng Thank you for your answer. If I understand you correctly, since the link shows, I am trying to make the connection through `HTTPS`. So it couldn't be a problem. Anyway, thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Some IP ranges are blocked by infrastructure network of Google Colab and prevent sending/receiving packets. I mean ranges related to certain countries or regions, [Google has listed them](https://support.google.com/cloudidentity/answer/2891389?hl=en#:%7E:text=Google%20Workspace%20is%20available%20in,%2C%20North%20Korea%2C%20and%20Syria.). `141.ir` server(s) affected due to routing related to those locations.

Due to the impossibility of establishing a direct connection, a proxy facilitates our work. As a simple idea, you can temporarily set HTTP(S) Proxy environment variables inside your notebook.

```bash
%env http_proxy=xx.xx.xx.xx:xx
%env https_proxy=xx.xx.xx.xx:xx
```

After doing the desired work, you can unset this proxy:

```bash
%env http_proxy=''
%env https_proxy=''
```

Here is an example: [bypass-google-colab-ip-restrictions.ipynb](https://colab.research.google.com/gist/alireza-rezaee/61fd0f0eae6a64bcc2276b178ce6485b/bypass-google-colab-ip-restrictions.ipynb)

Answer (score 0):

One safe way is to use unix commands in colab. to do so, you have to insert "!" before the command.

for example, if you run the following command:

```
! ls
```

it will list all the items in your running colab path.

another example :

```
!wget http://nlp.stanford.edu/data/glove.42B.300d.zip -P /my/colab/path/
!mkdir /my/colab/path/glove/
!unzip /my/colab/path/glove.42B.300d.zip -d /my/colab/path/glove/
```

these 3 lines of code will download the glove data set and unzip it to the defined version.

this process is the same for rar files.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have used commands exactly as you mentioned in your answer. Unfortunately, it didn't work either. I eventually came to an understanding that the problem is with the link itself. Anyway, I downloaded the desired data using a PHP script.